# Can you use logical operators in BigQuery to select different dates depending on current date?

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, logical-operators

At my work we run a report a couple times a week to pull some information from BigQuery.

We run the report every Monday and Thursday.

I'd like to automate the report to run on these days and want to know if I can put in some logic so that if I run the report on a Monday, it runs the data for the previous business week (Sunday - Saturday), and if I run the report on a Thursday, it runs the report for the current business week so far (Sunday - Wednesday).

On another report where I only run the report for previous week I use:

`select last_day(current_date - 14, week(monday)) as lw_week_start, last_day(current_date - 7, week(sunday)) as lw_week_end`

And to get the current week dates I can use:

`select last_day (current_date -7, week(monday)), (current_date -1)`

So can I put both of these in my query, and use some sort of logic to say, if I run on a Monday use the first one, if I run on a Thursday, use the second one?

Thanks

Comment: Can you Schedule two different queries to run for Monday and Thursday.

Comment: Yes - we can do that. But at the moment, we are in the process of trying making some additional reports which will also have a mid-week run too. So it would just be a nicer to not have an additional query for each of these reports.
Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the period as a CTE (or if you prefer as variables) and then use that information in the query:

```
with period as (
      select (case when extract(dayofweek from current_date) = 2
                   then last_day(date_add(current_date, interval -14 day), week(monday)) 
                   when extract(dayofweek from current_date) = 5
                   then last_day(date_add(current_date, interval -7 day), week(monday))                    
              end) as lw_week_start,
             (case when extract(dayofweek from current_date) = 2
                   then last_day(date_add(current_date, interval -7 day), week(sunday) 
                   when extract(dayofweek from current_date) = 5
                   then date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)
                   
              end) as lw_week_end
             
     )
select . . .
from period cross join
     . . .
```

Notes:

- This only includes Mondays and Thursdays.  I imagine you want to extend this to the other days of the week.
- `current_date` is the current date UTC.  You might want to include your timezone:

  ```
    select current_date('America/New_York')
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This one seems to have worked well as I was hard-coding the dates I needed into a CTE already, so I just copied this over and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Sorry, my first time posting. Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* if current_date is monday then it will return previous week report 
else it will give report for present week for any other current_date */

IF (EXTRACT (DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE)) = 2 THEN
select last_day(current_date - 14, week(monday)) as lw_week_start, last_day(current_date - 7, week(sunday)) as lw_week_end;
ELSE 
select last_day (current_date -7, week(monday)) as week_start, (current_date -1) as previous_day ;
END IF
```

[Scripting on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare)

[BigQuery Date fuctions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract)

Comment: Thank you for this! :) greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below to your `where` clause

```
where your_date_column in unnest(
  case extract(dayofweek from current_date())  
  when 2 then generate_date_array(last_day(current_date() - 14, week(monday)), last_day(current_date() - 7, week(sunday))) 
  when 5 then generate_date_array(last_day (current_date() - 7, week(monday)), current_date() - 1)
  end
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using the below one from Gordon as I have my date info in a CTE. But I'm sure I will find a use for this one also as it seems to work great too!